# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory error while generating project in Docker

Tags: node.js, gitlab, hexo

I have a long running project in Hexo, and recently I wanted to update it to the newest version (6.3.0). Once done, the project works properly with no problems locally on `macOS` and builds properly with `Docker` locally, but when running it on GitLab CI I receive the following error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '<directory>'
```

`Dockerfile` for testing:

```
FROM node:18.15.0-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache yarn

CMD ["sh", "-c", "yarn install && yarn run generate && ls -l public"]
```

`package.json` used:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "hexo": {
    "version": "6.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "./node_modules/hexo/bin/hexo server --draft",
    "generate": "./node_modules/hexo/bin/hexo generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hexo": "6.3.0",
    "hexo-generator-archive": "2.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-category": "2.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-feed": "3.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-index": "3.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-tag": "2.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-ejs": "2.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-marked": "6.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-stylus": "2.1.0",
    "hexo-server": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Run locally:

```
docker build -t my-project .
docker run -it -rm my-project
```

All is working as expected. Project is generated just fine.

But when I execute this `Dockerfile` in GitLab CI I get the errors.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:20.10.23

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:20.10.23-dind

before_script:
  - docker info

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker build -t my-project .
    - docker run my-project
```

I assume this has something to do with permissions or Node.js setup in the container, but I can't find what it can be.

I tried thousands of different things to solve the issue, went through multiple SO questions, docs and I am stuck:

- tried Docker in Docker builds on Gitlab, but also regular container builds - previously it just worked fine.
- tried different Docker images versions
- tried different versions of `Node.js` runtime, tried with `npm` and `yarn`

Update:

This is definitely issue with Hexo and Node.js runtime. With Node.js 12 all is working fine. Upgrading Node.js to 14 (and later) causes the build to fail. Tested with Hexo 3, 5, 6 and 7.

```
FATAL {
68  err: [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'some-path'] {
69    errno: -21,
70    code: 'EISDIR',
71    syscall: 'open',
72    path: 'some-path'
73  }
74} Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: %s https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
```

So it seems the only option for now is to stick to Node.js 12, but then there are no options to update Hexo as newer packages require Node.js 14 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation and reporting this to Hexo GitHub I finally found the solution that fixed the issue.

It was related to the `permalink` property in meta of the blog post entry.

I modified `permalink` property for each blog post and I appended `/index.html` to it:

Before:

`permalink: selenium/selenium-manager`

After:

`permalink: selenium/selenium-manager/index.html`

Once this was done, all started to work like a charm.

The original comment that helped me in finding the solution: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/4682#issuecomment-1149868769